# Connect Webpage to AWS IoT to Publish Messages

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, web-services, industry-4.0, web-sockets

I want to create an IoT system. My system contains a robotic arm, a CNC machine and a web page. I want to use MQTT in which I can publish from  my web page to robotic arm to pick up the object and put it on the table of the CNC machine. My problem is that I don't know how to connect the web page to AWS IoT and publish messages from my page to the robotic arm.

This question is not a duplicate of connect CNC to AWS IoT, I was asking there about how to connect CNC machine to IoT and here I am asking about how to use a webpage to send messages. I want to start the manufacturing process when I press the push button on my webpage. All I found is how to make the messages come to you in your browser, I can't find examples showing me how I can send messages from my webpage.

This is a followup of [this question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1953).

Answer (score 4):

AWS IoT supports MQTT over Websockets which can be used from with in the client side of a web application.

You can follow the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#mqtt-ws) for details of how to do the required authentication.

Comment: Could you add the essential points / lines of code from the linked source? Link only answers are discouraged by SE rules.

Comment: Only if we agree to close the question as having done no upfront research

Comment: Also the answer is "MQTT over Websockets", the link is just extra info about how to go about doing authentication in a AWS world (but yeah, it's not the greatest answer in the world, to not the greatest question)