# How can I get access to a public MQTT broker's (like iot.eclipse.org) logs?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, eclipse-iot

There was this recent [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/2464/14) in which the OP used [iot.eclipse.org](https://iot.eclipse.org/getting-started#sandbox-mqtt) as an MQTT broker. This server actually runs the latest released version of [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) broker.

I have advised to check the connection on the broker side and I have checked what are the possibilities. I could not find a way to access the [logs](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/956/how-to-enable-detailed-logging-of-mosquitto-broker-on-windows-7) provided by iot.eclipse.org's Mosquitto broker.

Anyway does someone know a way to get information about my client from a public broker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribing to `$SYS/#` topic will provide some information about the broker and maybe about the clients. Detailed description of these items can be found [here](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/SYS-Topics).

There are three main categories to highlight:

> - **Static Topics**: Messages on a static `$SYS` topic are not required to be sent on every `$SYS` topic update interval. These messages are
>     sent once the broker subscribes to the $SYS topic
> - **Required Topics**: Every broker which claims to support the `$SYS` topics should support these topics.
> - **Optional Topics**: A broker implementation may decide if it implements an optional topic.

The one needed to for client status check falls into the "Optional Topics" category.

- `$SYS/clients/[client-id]/ip`
- `$SYS/clients/[client-id]/connectedtime`

Also, based on this [description](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-logging/) about Mosquitto's logging, the console log can be logged into a topic (`$SYS/broker/log/#`) as well.

> Two common question are:
>
> - Can I see all connected clients?
> - Can I list all topics?
>
> The broker doesn’t let you do this directly but by enabling logging to
>   a a topic and monitoring the topic with an MQTT client you can get a
>   good idea.

Probably for privacy and/or security reasons iot.eclipse.org does not have topics for these log entries.

- No topics for `$SYS/clients/`

  [image]
- No topics for `$SYS/broker/log/#`

  [image]

For other public brokers these optional topics may exist, you can check them easily with [mqtt-spy](https://kamilfb.github.io/mqtt-spy/) for example.